# How to Bind/Provide Activity or Fragment with Hilt?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to implement Hilt on an Android App, while It's pretty easy to implement and removes a lot of the boilerplate code when comparing with Dagger, there are some things I miss, Like building my own components and scoping them myself so i'll have my own hirerchy.

To the point: Example: let's say I have a simple App with a RecyclerView, Adapter, Acitivity, and a Callback nested in my Adapter that I pass into my Adapter constructor in order to detect clicks or whatever, and I'm letting my activity implement that Callback, and of course I want to inject the adapter.

```
class @Inject constructor (callBack: Callback): RecyclerView.Adapter...
```

When I let Hilt know that I want to inject my adapter I need to let Hilt know how to provide all the Adapter dependencies - the Callback.

In Dagger I was able to achieve this by just binding the Activity to the Callback in one of my modules:

```
@Binds fun bindCallback(activity: MyActivity): Adapter.Callback
```

Dagger knew how to bind the Activity(or any Activity/Fragment) and then it was linked to that Callback, but with Hilt it does'nt work.

How can I achieve this? How can I provide or Bind Activity or Fragment with Hilt?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The solution is quite simple.

So a few days ago I came back to look at my question only to see that there was still no new solution, so I tried Bartek solution and wasn't able to make it work, and even if it did work, the clean Hilt code was becoming too messy, so I did a little investigation and played a little and discovered that the solution is actually stupidly easy.

It goes like this:

App:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApp: Application()
```

Activity: (implements callback)

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SomeClass.Callback {

    @Inject
    lateinit var someClass: SomeClass

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)  
    }

    override fun onWhatEver() {
        // implement
    }
}
```

SomeClass: (with inner callback)

```
class SomeClass @Inject constructor(
    private val callback: Callback
) {

    fun activateCallback(){
        callback.onWhatEver()
    }

    interface Callback{
        fun onWhatEver()
    }
}
```

SomeModule: (providing/binding the activity to the callback)

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
object SomeModule{

    @Provides
    fun provideCallback(activity: Activity) =
        activity as SomeClass.Callback
    
}
```

And that's all we need.
We cannot bind the activity to the callback with @Bind because it needs to be explicitly provided and cast to the callback so that the app can build.

The module is installed in ActivityComponent and is aware of a generic 'activity', if we cast it to the callback, Hilt is content and the activity is bound to the callback, and Hilt will know how to provide the callback as long as its in the specific activity scope.

**Multiple Activities/Fragments**

App:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApp: Application()
```

BooksActivity:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class BooksActivity : AppCompatActivity(), BooksAdapter.Callback{

        @Inject
        lateinit var adapter: BooksAdapter

        ...

        override fun onItemClicked(book: Book) {...}
    }
}
```

AuthorsActivity:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class AuthorsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), AuthorsAdapter.Callback{

    @Inject
    lateinit var adapter: AuthorsAdapter

    ...

    override fun onItemClicked(author: Author) {...}
}
```

BooksAdapter

```
class BooksAdapter @Inject constructor (
    val callback: Callback
) ... {

    ...

    interface Callback{
        fun onItemClicked(book: Book)
    }
}
```

AuthorsAdapter

```
class AuthorsAdapter @Inject constructor (
    val callback: Callback
) ... {

    ...

    interface Callback{
        fun onItemClicked(auhtor: Auhtor)
    }
}
```

AuhtorsModule

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
object AuthorsModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideCallback(activity: Activity) =
        activity as AuthorsAdapter.Callback
}
```

BooksModule

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
object BooksModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideCallback(activity: Activity) =
        activity as BooksAdapter.Callback
}
```

The Modules can be joined to one module with no problem, just change the names of the functions.

This is offcourse applicable for more activities and/or multiple fragments.. for all logical cases.

Comment: Cool that you figured this out for your case! Congrats!
My two cents: I'd take a more complex but explicit dependency component structure rather than a runtime, unchecked cast buried deep in the `Module` structure, every day of the week. In any project that has more than one `Activity` your approach is simply asking for trouble.

Comment: Since the whole valueable discussion has been removed, here's the summary: my **opinion** is that this is a very bad choice. Surely it **ISN'T** like the author suggested in a (now removed) comment: a "solution [...] perfect for all cases". Use with utmost care.

Answer (score 6):

Hilt can provide an instance of the generic `Activity` (and `Fragment` for that matter) as a dependency within the `ActivityComponent` (and `FragmentComponent` respectively). It's just not able to provide an instance of your specific `MyActivity`.

You can still [create your own `Component` in Hilt](https://dagger.dev/hilt/custom-components). You will just have to manage the `component` instance on your own. Add the `MyActivity` as the seed data for the component builder and you should be able to `@Bind` your `Callback` with no problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, while it is a good answer, I'm waiting for a better solution, cleaner hopefully, if there is none then I'll accept your answer. (also would be nice if you can provide a code example)

Comment: an example of creating a custom component?

Comment: Hi @BartekLipinski, can you add an example of custom component, which help to inject a specify activity into a class?