# Providing "MyFragment" to the module in Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I'm migrating from Dagger2 to Hilt however I'm unable to solve this part:

```
@Module
class HistoryPurchaseModule(private val historyPurchaseFragment: HistoryPurchaseFragment) {

@Provides
fun provideHistoryPurchaseFragment(): HistoryPurchaseFragment = historyPurchaseFragment

@Provides
fun provideUseCase() = HistoryPurchaseUseCase()

@Provides
fun provideSession() = HistoryPurchaseSession(
    isHistoryLoading = MutableLiveData(true),
    isThisTheFirstTime = true,
    isHistoryEmpty = MutableLiveData(false)
)

@Provides
fun provideViewModel(session: HistoryPurchaseSession): HistoryPurchaseViewModel {
    return historyPurchaseFragment.createViewModel {
        HistoryPurchaseViewModel(session)
    }
}

@Provides
fun provideLogic(
    useCases: HistoryPurchaseUseCase,
    viewModel: HistoryPurchaseViewModel
) = HistoryPurchaseLogic(viewModel.viewModelScope.coroutineContext, useCases, historyPurchaseFragment, viewModel)
}
```

My logic class takes two `interfaces` in the constructor that the viewModel(`HistoryPurchaseContract.ViewModel`) and fragment(`HistoryPurchaseContract.View`) implement.

Fragment:

```
class HistoryPurchaseFragment : BaseFragment<HistoryPurchaseEvent>(), HistoryPurchaseContract.View
```

ViewModel:

```
class HistoryPurchaseViewModel @Inject constructor(override var session: HistoryPurchaseSession) : BaseViewModel<HistoryPurchaseEvent>(),
HistoryPurchaseContract.ViewModel
```

I managed to pass the viewModel however I'm unable to pass the fragment.
Is there a way I can do it?

Comment: So so you want to inject something into fragment right?

Comment: I need to inject the fragment in the logic class. In dagger2 I can pass the fragment in the module constructor and then use it to instantiate the logic.

Comment: look it up 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63207731/how-to-bind-provide-activity-or-fragment-with-hilt

Comment: I'v seen that one, however in the comments they say it's not optimal.