# Android Hilt : fragment needs to be provided for

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I am converting an old app to HILT however I am having some difficulties with an interface.

fragment having the issue

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class mainFragment : baseFragment(), Listener
```

My fragment implements a interface called Listener

viewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class PviewModel @Inject constructor @Inject constructor(val listener: Listener) :  baseViewModel()
```

I found what I thought was a possible solution here [How to Bind/Provide Activity or Fragment with Hilt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63207731/how-to-bind-provide-activity-or-fragment-with-hilt) but it gives me an error about providing the fragment still

here is the module

```
@Module
@InstallIn(FragmentComponent::class)
object FragmentModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideCallback(fragment: mainFragment) =
        fragment as Listener
}
```

Error itself
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] ....mainFragment cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.

Comment: I hope you have added ```@AndroidEntryPoint``` on activity in which you have used fragments

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani yes I have